# Is ObjC still used for iOS development?

Tags: ios

On the WWDC in 2014 Apple announced that they are changing from Objective-C to Swift, for developing native iOS applications. (Is this correct? The change took place in 2014?)

It is my understanding that Objective-c comes from C. (Is this correct?)
It is also my understanding that the operative system iOS is built using C, C++, Objective-C and Swift. (Is this correct?)
Lastly, it is my understanding that, in 2018, apps for iOS are built using Swift. (Is this correct?)

I have a few questions regarding this subject:
1. In 2018, do anyone use only objective-c to develop iOS apps?
2. Is it possible to mix Swift and objective-c, and how common is it?
3. Is it safe to say that objective-c has been more or less abandoned and Swift is the mayor language when developing apps for the iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, many companies (including Apple, Facebook, Booking.com) still use Objective-C for writing apps.
2. Yes, it is perfectly safe to mix Swift and Objective-C.
3. No, Objective-C has not been abandoned. Although its usage is shrinking.